# PDF export in Data table using Tabletools with large number of column create unsymmetrical or non-formated data in PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, datatables

I have created one sample table which have 24 column, Now i want to export this table into PDF, I am using table tools of datatable

Please find the sample for this issue

http://jsfiddle.net/ashukasama/c8YWK/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table').dataTable({
        "bSort": false,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bFilter": false,
        dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        tableTools: {
            "sSwfPath": "http://lucentinnovation.com/demo/badmc/charts/plugins/datatables/tabletools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        }
    });
});
```

I need to format it correctly.

Comment: Your table is too broad - hence the compressed format you're experiencing. See now: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8YWK/4/)

Comment: @urbz yes I know that, I am looking for solution for this/

Comment: Check out [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) and/or [mpdf](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php). Might help you out